# How to add the "filetype" to the default "statusline" in Vim?

Tags: statusline

I like the default `statusline` in Vim, but would you like to add the `filetype` to it.

Is it possible to add the `filetype` to the default `statusline` without having to create a new `statusline` from scratch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Simple status line: filename and filetype

As you can see with `:set statusline?`, the default `'statusline'` option is empty in vim. You'll need to overwrite it.

Here's the most simple example with filename and filetype:

```
set statusline=%f%=%{&filetype}
```

- `%f` : filename
- `%=` : separation between left and right
- `%{filetype}` : obviously, the file type

See `:h 'statusline'` for more examples and other details.

#### Adding the mode

If you want to show the `mode` you're in, you can write a dictionary to get the string you expect depending on the result of `mode()`.

This is how I set it:

```
let g:currentmode={
  \ '__'     : '- ',
  \ 'c'      : 'C ',
  \ 'i'      : 'I ',
  \ 'ic'     : 'I ',
  \ 'ix'     : 'I ',
  \ 'n'      : 'N ',
  \ 'multi'  : 'M ',
  \ 'ni'     : 'N ',
  \ 'no'     : 'N ',
  \ 'R'      : 'R ',
  \ 'Rv'     : 'R ',
  \ 's'      : 'S ',
  \ 'S'      : 'S ',
  \ '^S'     : 'S ',
  \ 't'      : 'T ',
  \ 'v'      : 'V ',
  \ 'V'      : 'V ',
  \ '^V'     : 'V ',
  \}
```

Note that `^S` and `^V` are single characters produced by typing `<c-v>X` in insert mode (where `X` is whatever alphabetic character).

Now, `g:current_mode[mode()]` will give the right-hand side string depending on `mode()`. Adjust it to your liking, whith the help of `:h mode()`.

Here is the new statusline showing the mode at the beginning (between spaces):

```
set statusline=\ %{g:curentmode[mode()]}\ %f%=%{&filetype}
```